# Dead lock detection- Gemfire 8

Tags: deadlock, gemfire

I defined a GemFire region with RegionShortcut.PARTITION and setRedundantCopies(1).
3 applications, running on 3 different VMs are making use of these region.

It seems that I have a dead lock when I'm shutting down the VM of the application that has just inserted an item to the cache (the "owner" of the item):

*The blocked process: blocked before region.put.

*The blocking process: seemed to be blocked after trying to remove old entries from the region. I suspect that this operation is invoked by the destruction mechanism provided by the CacheListenerAdapter.

I've read some documentation about this issue in the following links:
[CacheListener Interface API](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vfabric-gemfire/661-api/com/gemstone/gemfire/cache/CacheListener.html) and this [blog](https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/201298393-How-to-avoid-detect-distributed-dead-lock) that mainly found the usage of the listeners to blame.

Yet it seems that this issues were addressed and fixed in GemFire 6.x versions [for example: [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/vfabric-gemfire/doc/BugsFixedGemFire662.html) and [here]](http://www.gemstone.com/docs/bugnotes.html)

So, I would like to ask:

1) Is this issues reported for Gemfire 8? or 7?

2) what is the recommended work-around for this issue? 3 different work-arounds are mentioned [here](https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/201298393-How-to-avoid-detect-distributed-dead-lock). Are there any other? any preferred one?

Just for reference, the blocking process's thread dump is as followed:

```
Owner stack trace: java.lang.Throwable
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.lockInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.BucketRegion.lockPrimaryStateReadLock(BucketRegion.java:780)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.BucketRegion.doLockForPrimary(BucketRegion.java:719)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.BucketRegion.beginLocalWrite(BucketRegion.java:704)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.BucketRegion.basicDestroy(BucketRegion.java:1105)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.PartitionedRegionDataStore.destroyLocally(PartitionedRegionDataStore.java:1511)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.PartitionedRegion.destroyInBucket(PartitionedRegion.java:5440)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.PartitionedRegionDataView.destroyExistingEntry(PartitionedRegionDataView.java:45)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.PartitionedRegion.basicDestroy(PartitionedRegion.java:5317)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.validatedDestroy(LocalRegion.java:1330)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.destroy(LocalRegion.java:1317)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.AbstractRegion.destroy(AbstractRegion.java:282)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.remove(LocalRegion.java:9513)
```

Answer (score 1):

Deadlocks involving CacheListeners are possible. The behavior is documented in the latest (GemFire 8.1) javadoc.  Here is the relevant excerpt from the CacheListener documentation:

> **Avoiding the risk of deadlock**
>
> The methods on a CacheListener are invoked while holding a lock on the entry described by the EntryEvent, as a result if the listener method takes a long time to execute then it will cause the operation that caused it to be invoked to take a long time. In addition, listener code which calls Region methods could result in a deadlock. For example, in afterUpdate(EntryEvent) for entry key k1, put(k2, someVal) is called at the same time afterUpdate(EntryEvent) for entry key k2 calls put(k1, someVal) a deadlock may result. This co-key dependency example can be extended to a co-Region dependency where listener code in Region "A" performs Region operations on "B" and listener code in Region "B" performs Region operations on "A". Deadlocks may be either java-level or distributed multi-VM dead locks depending on Region configuration. To be assured of no deadlocks, listener code should cause some other thread to access the region and must not wait for that thread to complete the task.